# torch.sum with a condition inside

Tags: pytorch, metrics, recommendation-engine

I am trying to make a recommendation system, I tried to use a function which calculates me the hit@10 which is as follows:

```
def RecEvaluate(model, g, features, users_eval, movies_eval, neg_sample_size):
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        neg_movies_eval = data.neg_valid[users_eval].flatten()
        r, neg_r = model.est_rating(g, features, users_eval, movies_eval, neg_movies_eval)
        hits10 = (torch.sum(neg_r > r, 1) <= 10).numpy()
        print('HITS@10:{:.4f}'.format(np.mean(hits10)))
        return np.mean(hits10)
```

I especially want to understand this line

```
hits10 = (torch.sum(neg_r > r, 1) <= 10).numpy()
```

for the sake of understanding, I made an attempt and executed this piece of code as example:

```
neg_r = torch.tensor([[1., 10. ,5., 1., 2., 4.],[0., 7., 8., 10., 6., 2.]])
r = torch.tensor([[1., 9. ,5., 1., 2., 3.]])
#####################################################################
r = r.T
r.shape
neg_r = neg_r.T
neg_r.shape

print(neg_r > r)
print(torch.sum(neg_r > r))
print(torch.sum(neg_r > r, 1))
print(torch.sum(neg_r > r, 1) <= 10)
hits10 = (torch.sum(neg_r > r, 1) <= 10).numpy()
print(hits10)
print('HITS@10:{:.4f}'.format(np.mean(hits10)))
```

and I got the following result:

```
torch.Size([6, 1])
torch.Size([6, 2])
tensor([[False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False,  True],
        [False,  True],
        [False,  True],
        [ True, False]])
tensor(5)
tensor([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
tensor([True, True, True, True, True, True])
[ True  True  True  True  True  True]
HITS@10:1.0000
```

how does it work? is this how we calculate the Hit@10 ?
and finally if it is correct? how can we calculate ARHRs @ 10 in this case?

Comment: What do you refer to as *Hit@10* and *ARHRs@10*?

Comment: Hit@10 is  the hit rate =  the number of hits in the top-recommendations/ the total number of user ....and ARHRs@10 is  average reciprocal hit-rank = is a weighted version of Hit rate, which takes the ranking position of the testitemin the list of recommendations into account.

Comment: It's still quite unclear what is the *number of hits*? Does *N* refer to *10* in this specific instance? What is `model.est_rating` returning, in other word what are `r`, and `neg_r`?

Comment: yes N in my case is 10, but just focus on the example below and the line hits10 = (torch.sum(neg_r > r, 1) <= 10).numpy()

Comment: If you want to understand the problem, you need to look at it in its entirety. I repeat my question to you: what are `r` and `neg_r`? I can't just guess why `torch.sum(neg_r > r, 1) <= 10)` is computed if I don't know what each operand represents. Do you get my point?

Comment: r: the predicted score  of items rated by user u. and neg_r: is a negative rating ... in my example the shape of r is torch.Size([6, 1]) and the shape of neg_r is torch.Size([6, 2])